# Integration of Google Calendar with amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-calendar-api, ec2-api-tools

I am using Google calendar and based on calendar booking i want to start AWS EC2 instances.

Is there a way to achieve this interaction?

Answer (score 0):

A very good use case actually; it is really cool.

This is one of the ways you can plan the design and architecture. You would be making use of the Google Calender API endpoint using REST or SDK to continuously (asynchronously) poll the events and activities; depending on how you specify the EC2 instance to be started or stopped. You can obtain the information from Calendar data. Based on this you can start or stop the instance via. the AWS SDK.

There AWS SDKs are available for almost all the popular programming languages - .net, java, php, ruby, python and also Google Go. If not you can always fall back with the REST API calls and the same.

I recommend you to take a look at Skeedly to get some ideas. - http://www.skeddly.com/